# :focus on class doesn't work

Tags: html, css, hover, focus

I want the class to appear a different color after selected. Why does it just go back to the non `active` color? what can I do so that it stays focused on my class?

I tried many things on this forum but nothing seems to work. I need it for school really quickly.

```css
.Auswahl {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  border: none;
  margin-right: -4px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}
.Auswahl:hover {
  background-color: #FF0004;
}
.Auswahl:active {
  background-color: #00FF2B;
}
.Auswahl:focus {
  background-color: #7100FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="Auswahl">
  <h1>Sparkasse</h1>
  <br>Vorteile
  <br>Nachteile
</div>
```

Comment: Im afraid there is no onClick function for CSS, the closest you will get is :active without the help of Javascript

Comment: `focus` won't work for `divs` it is for `input` etc

Comment: @Akshay That is not true. Any element may have `:focus` applied to it.

Comment: @TylerH really i thought they worked for `button` `input` etc

Comment: You can do it if you are willing to lose your hover effect http://jsfiddle.net/n1bo49ts/

Answer (score 2):

> The :focus pseudo-class applies while an element has the focus
>   (accepts keyboard events or other forms of text input).

More info **[here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)**

Change your HTML like this:

```css
.Auswahl {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  border: none;
  margin-right: -4px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}
.Auswahl:hover {
  background-color: #FF0004;
}
.Auswahl:focus {
  background-color: #7100FF;
}
.Auswahl:active {
  background-color: #00FF2B;
}
```

```html
<button class="Auswahl">
  <h1>Sparkasse</h1>
  <br>Vorteile
  <br>Nachteile
</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this. It's got a very small amount of jQuery to add a new class on click.

**HTML**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<div class="Auswahl">
    <h1>Sparkasse</h1>
    <br>Vorteile
    <br>Nachteile
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Auswahl {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  border: none;
  margin-right: -4px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}
.Auswahl:hover {
  background-color: #FF0004;
}
.Auswahl:active {
  background-color: #00FF2B;
}
.Auswahl:focus {
  background-color: #7100FF;
}

.newClass {
  background-color: #7100FF;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".Auswahl").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('newClass');
});
```

Here's a Codepen example too: [EXAMPLE HERE](http://codepen.io/alandunning/pen/GgmyZB)

Comment: .toggleClass would be a better choice wouldn't it?

Comment: @JustinBreiland It would indeed, I changed it. Was it specified that it had to change back in the question? Anyway, thanks for the suggestion. It is a better way.

Comment: CSS would be a better choice than introducing jQuery for a simple CSS property.

Comment: @TylerH Agreed, I was just providing options as the CSS alternative was already suggested as an answer.

Comment: It's a css question with a css answer, if it had a javascript/jquery tag then by all means provide more sub-optimal options.